# Django DateTimeRangeField used with date_hierarchy

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

I have a `DateTimeRangeField` that I'd like to use with django's `date_hierarchy` but `date_hierarchy` needs a `DateField` or `DateTimeField`.

I've written a function to convert the range into a datetime using `range.lower`, but using a callable doesn't seem to work.

eg.

```
@admin.register(models.MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(AdvancedModelAdmin):

    date_hierarchy = 'date_range_to_datetime'

    def date_range_to_datetime(instance):
        """
        Return a datetime from django date range.
        """
        return instance.range.lower
```

Is there a way to use a `DateTimeRangeField` with `date_hierarchy`?

Answer (score 0):

Despite what some other places claim, this ***can*** be done. But you need to do two things. Firstly you need to annotate on the lower value. And then you need to tell the static-Admin-checks to skip the `_check_date_hierarchy` check.

It's actually not that hard in practice, but you have to know what you're doing. Here's a very condensed version of this in action. `timeframe` is the DateTimeRangeField. Just be careful that what you are using as your date_hierarchy value is valid to the datebase, or it'll blow all the way up.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields.ranges import RangeStartsWith

class SkipDateHeirarchyChecks(admin.checks.ModelAdminChecks):
    def _check_date_hierarchy(self, obj):
        return []

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    date_hierarchy = 'starts'
    checks_class = SkipDateHeirarchyChecks

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request).annotate(
            starts=RangeStartsWith('timeframe')
        )
```